# The boolean return statement inside a for loop and if statement is always returning false in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to return a boolean output from the function "checkUser" and then to print an output for that. But for every run, it is always returning 'false' even though the conditions are correct. I have used an object to save the boolean result because the return statement is not working inside the 'if'.
Also, I am getting the prompt- 'method breakpoint' in 'getCheck()' function. Is there any thing wrong I am doing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class myclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Bank[] bk=new Bank[4];
        System.out.println("Enter the Name, Age and the Acc No. of 3 users : ");
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        //System.out.print("Enter the Name : ");
        String name=sc.next();
        //System.out.print("Enter the age : ");
        int age=sc.nextInt();
        //System.out.print("Enter the Account Number : ");
        int acc_no=sc.nextInt();
        bk[i]=new Bank(name, age, acc_no);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the Account no to validate a user : ");
        int acc_chk=sc.nextInt();
        
        // method calling
        boolean c=checkUser(bk, acc_chk);
        
        // Outputs
        if(c)
        System.out.println("The user account exits!");
    else
        System.out.println("The user account does not exit!");


}
    // method to check the authenticity of the user
    public static boolean checkUser(Bank[] obj, int ac_no) {

        //boolean ch;
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            if(ac_no==obj[i].getAcc()) {
                obj[i].setCheck(true);
                j=i;
            }

        }
        return obj[j].getCheck();
        }
        

    

}
class Bank{
    String name;
    int age;
    int acc;
    String type;
    boolean check;
    
    public Bank(String s, int a, int b) {
        
    }
    public void setName(String s) {this.name=s;}
    public void setAge(int a){this.age=a;}
    public void setAcc(int b){this.acc=b;}
    public void setType(String t) {this.type=t;}
    public void setCheck(boolean ch){this.check=ch;}
    
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public int getAge() {return age;}
    public int getAcc() {return acc;}
    public String getType() {return type;}
    public boolean getCheck() {return check;}
}
```

Comment: have you ever used a debugger?

Comment: First thing is you need to initialize the ch variable, since it is a local variable and why are you using obj[0] , it should be obj[i] instead.

Comment: try to use meaningful variable name. `j=obj[i].getAcc()` is way harder to understand than something like `acc = banks[i].getAcc()` (or even `getAccountNumber()`. Long varaible won't make your program slower but will make reading your program waaaaay faster

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi where? From what I'm seeing they are initializing it before it's used. Also, `ch` is a `bool`, it gets initialized to `false` on declaration anyway.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca , first line of the method checkUser

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi `ch` is initialized, but you are right for `obj[0]`

Comment: I understand that by default it is initialized to false, but it is good to initialize them . Isnt it ?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi not really, and "you need" is not the same as "it's good". A better thing would have been to move the declaration just before use.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Initializing the variable 'ch' causing the return to give that initialized value instead of the value of the object. I used "j=obj[i].getAcc()" to see if this is affecting the output, earlier I had directly used the object value. I also had used obj[i] but that too was not making any difference. I had done the same you all are asking me to do, nothing had worked for me.

Comment: @Ibad `obj[0].setCheck(true);` shouldn't this be `obj[i].setCheck(true);`? I mean, the others may be for debugging, but this just insures that you'll always get the check done on the latest account and the validity set on the first one. In other words, if you *really* want to always check the first account for testing purposes, remove the loop altogether for your test and directly set the validity of the first account, otherwise you're only breaking the algorithm.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have changed the program as you described but still it is returning false. What to do now?

Comment: If you don't know how to use a debugger, user `System.out.println` to print intermediate values when you change them. As soon as you find a value that doesn't match what you expect at least you pinpointed where something went wrong and you can reason about why it went wrong. This is what I would do, and no offense but I won't do it for you when you can do it yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping me, everything was right and was working perfectly fine except the constructor `Bank`. It was not calling the setters so values were not stored in any variable and that's why boolean variable had the default value `false` which was returned by the function `checkUser`. Thanks @FedericoklezCulloca, I tried to print the intermediate values but nothing was printing so when I went to check the constructor I found the fault.

```
public Bank(String s, int a, int b) {
            this.setName(s);
            this.setAge(a);
            this.setAcc(b);
            
        }
```